# How to use different font style (bold and regular) on a radio button option text in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I need to make a part of the text bold in a radio button option

I need to achieve this output wherein "**Option A:**" font style is **bold** and "Pasta" is just regular font style. [radio button output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8ydV.png)

I've tried this code and string is data and it doesn't have font option

```
Public Class _1_5_register_event_s2
Private Sub _1_5_register_event_s2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim optionA As String = "Option A ($0):  "
    Dim food As String = "Pasta"

    optionA = FontStyle.Bold
    food = FontStyle.Regular

    rb_optionA.Text = optionA & food

End Sub
```

Comment: Assuming this is WinForms, I think you're going to have to fake this by using an option button with no caption, and two label controls, one of which is set to bold.

Comment: You have to draw it yourself. Subscribe to the Control's `Paint` event. `RadioButtonRenderer.GetGlyphSize(...)` gives you the size of the radio Button (to offset the Text), `RadioButtonRenderer.DrawParentBackground(...)` draws the *transparent* background (if the Control or its Parent have a solid background color, it's not needed, but better use it anyway). `TextRenderer.DrawText(...)` (with flags `TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter Or TextFormatFlags.Left Or TextFormatFlags.NoPadding`) draws the text. Build the bold Font using the Control's Font with a different `FontStyle`).

Comment: It would be better to create a custom control derived from RadioButton (assuming you're referring to WinForms, as the `Load` event suggests). This way, you can better handle the Text (you have to clear it before drawing) and you don't have to write the same code multiple times for different standard controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the radiobutton class.

Code:

Class

```
Public Class XRadioButton
    Inherits RadioButton

    Public Sub New()
        UseVisualStyleBackColor = False
        TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageAboveText
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Property Text As String
        Get
            Return ""
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            MyBase.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property LeftText As String
    Public Property RightText As String

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal pevent As PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(pevent)
        Dim rect As Rectangle = ClientRectangle
        rect.Inflate(-5, -5)

        Using sf As StringFormat = New StringFormat() With {
            .Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
            .LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far
        }

            Using brush As Brush = New SolidBrush(ForeColor)
                Dim font As Font = New Font(Me.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
                pevent.Graphics.DrawString(LeftText, font, brush, rect, sf)
                sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
                pevent.Graphics.DrawString(RightText, Me.Font, brush, rect, sf)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Form

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim button As XRadioButton = New XRadioButton()
        button.LeftText = "Hello"
        button.RightText = "test"
        Me.Controls.Add(button)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Result:
[image]